# How many steps in a cycle of pouring water from one jug to another?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

If one jug has M units  and another has N units, (M even, N odd)
and the only operation is doubling the contents of the
lesser by pouring from the greater, how many operations
does it take to return to the original configuration?

(M+N-1)/2 will do it since there are only (M+N-1) pairs with total M+N,
but shorter cycles are also possible.
Given M, and N  how can one predict the number of pourings needed
to return,  without actually doing all the steps empirically?

Also, What is the MINIMUM number of units a jug has in the course of a cycle?

Comment: Return to what 'original configuration'?  I am rather confused what you the goal is here ... Can you maybe give an example with concrete M and N?

Comment: here's an example--  Start with M=104, N=47                                                                                                 104  047
 094  057
 114  037
 074  077
 148  003
 006  145
 012  139
 024  127
 048  103
 096  055
 110  041
 082  069
 138  013
 026  125
 052  099
 Steps in the Cycle= 15
 because next step you are back to 104,  47  the starting values of M and N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $G:=M+N$ (which we know is odd). The operation here - on both jugs - is doubling $\bmod G$.  Looking just at the $M$ jug, you either have
$M\to 2M \quad$ or
$\begin{align}
M\to\  &G-2N \\ 
&= G-2(G-M) \\ 
&= 2M-G
\end{align}$

So the cycle length will divide the order of $2\bmod G$ (the smallest value $k$ such that $2^k\equiv 1 \bmod G$), which itself will divide the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(G)$.

The minimum cycle occurs when $M=2N$ for example $(M,N)=(6,3)$

If $G$ is prime and  $2$ is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) $\bmod G$, and assuming the jugs are labelled, you will have a full cycle of all $G{-}1$ possibilities for every starting configuration.

In the case $G=7$, we have that $2$ is not a primitive root, giving cycles of length $3$:

[image]

(here the blue squares are valid starting possibilities as defined, again taking the jugs as labelled)

---

For your example $M=104, N=47$, we have $G=151$ which is prime. The order of $2 \bmod 151$ will divide $151{-}1=150$ by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). We'd need to check the values of $2^i \bmod 151$ to find the cycle length; depending on what tools you have available, it's probably just as easy to run the calculation on $M$.

$104 \to 57 \to 114 \to 77 \to 3 \to 6 \to 12 \to 24 \to 48 \to 96 \to 41 \to 82 \to 13 \to 26 \to 52 \to 104$

So when $M\le 75$ - meaning $M<N$ - the next value is $2M$, otherwise the next value is $2M-151$ as I explained before.

I don't know of any particular shortcut that will give you the minimum values, unless you have a full cycle of $G-1$ (in which case the minimum is $1$).

---

For $G=185$, we have $185=5\times 37,$ then $\lambda(185) = {\rm lcm}( \lambda(37),\lambda(5)) = {\rm lcm}(36,4) = 36$ So we expect a cycle length of (or dividing) $36$ (marked jugs). Also, for initial states with multiples of $37$, we'd expect a cycle length of $4$.

Checking the cycle on $1$, we indeed get a cycle length of $36$ (the second half just being the same as the first but with jug quantities reversed). So there should be $5$ such cycles, since each cycle runs the the full set of congruences $\bmod 37$ (coprime to $37$) and there are $5$ of each such value in the range. And then the $4$-cycle on multiples of $37$ will complete the set, $5\times 36+4=184$.

The minimum value in the cycle will obviously not be a member of any other cycle. Also in the case of $G=185$ you know that $5$ and $37$ will be the smallest member of whichever cycles they are in, since they are prime divisors of $185$ and all quantities in that cycles will be divisible by those starter primes. But in general finding the minimum of every cycle is not quick. I believe it's always prime (or $1$).

Comment: Thank you Joffan.  I am not familiar with all the terms you use, so could you illustrate using my example of  M=104  N=47.  How do you get that the number of  steps in a cycle is 15,  and that the Minimum units ever in a jug is 3.

Comment: Which terms do you not understand? I'll see if I can explain further. Some of the terms are linked also.

Comment: Sticking to this example (M+N= G=151),  there are 75 pairs of numbers m,n  that add up to G.  It turns out that there are 5 different cycles of 15 pairs each.  The 5 cycles have 5 different minimums   which turn out to be 1,3,5,11 and 19.   Is there any method to anticipate this result-  i.e. that there will be 5 cycles of length 15 each, and their minimums will be 1,3,5,11 and 19??    For example when M=1 and N=184, G=185 it turns out that the 92 pairs fall into 6 cycles of 15 each and one cycle of 2.  Could this result be predicted by any method besides just doing it.

Comment: @stevenewman - Note that your result on $G=185$ was incorrect, as expected, since 15 does not divide 36. You should accept this answer, $\checkmark$ if you feel it has answered your question, and you can always ask another if you want to visit another aspect of this problem.

Comment: you're right.  I meant to say there were 5 cycles of 18 and one cycle of 2. I accept your answer completely.

Comment: I finally found that checkmart you refer to! i checked it..